# Why does go fmt allow empty brackets?

Tags: go

I was just wondering why these brackets haven't been removed after running **go fmt**, does their use have a function?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")

    {
        {
            {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/o6urIHGe17), thanks.

Comment: Does adding and removing code sound like the function of a *formatting* command?

Comment: @hobbs well the tool does remove whitespace and semicolons, its a good question imo

Comment: That would have been my response @Plato, I wanted to establish whether these Blocks constituted code at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brackets on their own denote code [Blocks](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks). From the spec:

> A block is a possibly empty sequence of declarations and statements within matching brace brackets.

These are part of the Go syntax, and `go fmt` formats them according the its formatting rules.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I'm going to read all of that spec before I pose anymore go questions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Imagine you wrote a layout template of code. Something like:
`if a == b {
} else {
}`

You would be pissed of if editor removes the `{}` when you hit Ctrl+S (some have auto-formatting enabled)

Answer (score 3):

They basically function like an internal namespace, so any definition(s) you put in between an encapsulating brace will not be visible outside of it.

```
// ... other code above ...

{
  a := 5 // declare a
}

a = 5 // compiler error, a is undeclared
```

And plus formatting tools such as `gofmt` or `autopep8` (for python) do not modify a given file beyond adding/removing whitespace or newline characters to already existing code.